# Calling fork on a multithreaded process

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, system-calls

I had a doubt on using fork on a multi-threaded process. 
If a process has multiple threads (already created using pthread_create and did a pthread_join) and I call fork, will it copy the same functions assigned to the threads in the child process or create a space where we can reassign the functions?

Comment: Just don't do it, OK?  I used to work on a product in which a multi-threaded process needed to occasionally start other processes.  Our strategy was to have it create a single-threaded helper process at startup, before it created any new threads. Then, whenever it needed to kick off a new child process, it would send a message to the helper, asking the helper to do it.

Comment: Ok, since you created a single threaded process and it started the new process, the child process always had a single thread (the main thread of execution)?

Comment: Just to be clear, The long-lived main process first created the helper process, and then it created many threads.  It never directly created any other process after creating the helper.  The helper process did _not_ create any new threads. It was strictly single-threaded, which made it safe for the helper to create new processes. The transient, child processes created by the helper had no restrictions. They could do whatever they needed to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read carefully what POSIX says about [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and threads.  In particular:

> - A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls `fork()`, the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.

The child process will have a single thread running in the context of the calling thread.  Other parts of the original process may be tied up by threads that no longer exist (so mutexes may be locked, for example).

The rationale section (further down the linked page) says:

> There are two reasons why POSIX programmers call `fork()`. One reason is to create a new thread of control within the same program (which was originally only possible in POSIX by creating a new process); the other is to create a new process running a different program. In the latter case, the call to `fork()` is soon followed by a call to one of the `exec` functions.
>
> The general problem with making `fork()` work in a multi-threaded world is what to do with all of the threads. There are two alternatives. One is to copy all of the threads into the new process. This causes the programmer or implementation to deal with threads that are suspended on system calls or that might be about to execute system calls that should not be executed in the new process. The other alternative is to copy only the thread that calls `fork()`. This creates the difficulty that the state of process-local resources is usually held in process memory. If a thread that is not calling `fork()` holds a resource, that resource is never released in the child process because the thread whose job it is to release the resource does not exist in the child process.
>
> When a programmer is writing a multi-threaded program, the first described use of `fork()`, creating new threads in the same program, is provided by the `pthread_create()` function. The `fork()` function is thus used only to run new programs, and the effects of calling functions that require certain resources between the call to `fork()` and the call to an exec function are undefined.

Comment: `the effects of calling functions that require certain resources between the call to fork() and the call to an exec function are undefined.` Could you explain what does this line mean? It's quite defined that such "intermediate" functions would have per-process resources and current-thread ones, but not the resources related with other threads. So what is "undefined" here?

Comment: @Mergasov — As a f'rinstance, suppose that thread T1 has `stderr` locked (see POSIX [`flockfile()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html)) because it is in a call to `fprintf(stderr, …)` when thread T2 calls `fork()`.  The parent process has no special problems, but the child process only has a single thread corresponding to T2 and that thread does not own the lock on `stderr`.  So, if the child needs to report an error, it will get stuck waiting for the lock to be released, but the lock will never be released.  That's an example of "certain resources".